# Dependency Injection on Java Collections API

Tags: java, collections, dependency-injection

I'm writing a Java component that will be doig pretty heavy-duty work on some big data. Obviously, therefore, efficiency (both speed and memory) is paramount.

I'm also just starting to work with IoC and dependency injection frameworks for the first time (such Spring AOP, Google Guice, etc.), and was wondering if they could help me out at all.

What I'd like to do is something like this (all throughout my code):

```
List<MyData> oMyData = new List<MyData>();
```

Then, in some XML config file (or however the framework configures injections), I would specify that every time an instance of List is created, to inject, say, an `ArrayList<MyData>` as its implementation.

This way, if, down the road, I decide to use a different implementation, or even something homegrown that suits my application more efficiently than anything provided by Java Collections, I only need to change the class that gets injected. No other modifications would be necessary, and my code will run that much more efficiently.

**Is this is a possible solution, or is this just big dreaming?** Again, because I'm so new to IoC frameworks it's tough to tell what objects injections will work on, whether generics can be preserved during injection, and all sorts of other complicating details I can't seem to find answers to anywhere else.

Thanks in advance for any insight or recommendations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not sound like a classic scenario for an IOC container, but you could use a factory method.

```
public static List<MyData> createDataList(){
    return new ArrayList<MyData>();
}
```

Use this factory method all over your app. Now if you want to use a different list implementation, just change this method. Look mom, no container needed.

Just to be clear: IOC is an awesome concept. But I don't think what you are talking about is a classic scenario for IOC.

Comment: Then from here, you could use IOC to choose different factories at run-time. AFAIK, IOC is about injecting instances of classes, not classes themselves, so the function wouldn't be static.

Comment: @Chris the approach with different factories is of course valid, but probably not for a task as basic as this one.

Comment: Thanks Sean! I do have a couple of reservations though. First off, although I'm still a fairly new enterprise developer, it has been beaten into me time and time again that factory methods are on their way "out" because they are difficult to test, and that dep. injections are the new way to go. Can you quickly explain why you think IOC is a great concept, but just not for this scenario? At the end of the day I want the best/most elegant solution, so I have no preference either way (factory or injection), I'm just curious about which scenarios call for factory vs. injection solutions. Thanks!

Comment: @Mara true, factory methods for business Objects are evil. But this is infrastructure stuff and here, factory methods are valid, as long as you keep them simple and universal. If you let your factory method return a list implementation that relies on a database or any other external preconditions, then I'll agree, IOC would be a lot better. But if you are just experimenting with Collection types, factory methods should suffice.

Comment: Last quick question - why are factory methods evil for business stuff? At the end of the day aren't they all just objects? I'm sure you are right I'm just not understanding the difference between an ArrayList or some bean floating around on an app server. Thanks again for all your help so far!

Comment: @Mara they are evil if they depend on external things like data bases. If you keep them side-effect free, and don't include any context-sensitive code, go ahead and use factory methods for business Objects as well.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
<util:list list-class="java.util.ArrayList" value-type="your.package.YourClass">
    <!-- list elements here -->
</util:list>
```

This comes out-of-the box with spring...

Answer (score 0):

What you are aiming is very much possible , and in fact a good recommended practice , also called as Dependency Injection.

You can use Spring for this. Ofcourse the exact syntax of injecting the object is going to be much different than what you show here.

IN Spring , for example , you would write

`List<MyData> oMyData = factory.getBean("MyData")`

IN a separate config file , you specify exactly what is `MyData` , and this will get injected.

Answer (score 0):

As said before your case description is somewhat unconventional for a DI solution. Especially to tune performance that way seams somewhat inappropriate. I suspect to really succeed on this you would even need more than one implementation for different places of injection. If you want to go for that I recommend to use [Silk DI](http://www.silkdi.com/). It allows to binds to different `List` implementations under different circumstances http://www.silkdi.com/userguide/binds.html#targeting with just a few bindings.